# Why does this C function have side effects?

Tags: c, malloc

Could someone help me understand what's wrong with this C program?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Box {
    int **value;
};
void nop(void) {
    /* Why does this function have side effects? */
    void *a = malloc(sizeof *a);
    free(a);
}
struct Box *makeBox(void) {
    int *value = NULL;
    struct Box *box = malloc(sizeof *box);
    box->value = &value;
    return box;
}
int main(void) {
    struct Box *box = makeBox();
    printf("Dereferenced: %p\n", *box->value);
    nop();
    printf("Dereferenced: %p\n", *box->value);
}
```

If I run it, it prints:

```
Dereferenced: (nil)
Dereferenced: 0x562831863727
```

However, if I comment out the `nop` function, I get:

```
Dereferenced: (nil)
Dereferenced: (nil)
```

Can someone help me understand why calling `nop` changes `*box->value`?

Comment: Another problem in `nop` is that `sizeof *a` should be a constraint violation (the expression `*a` has type `void`, and `void` doesn't have a size).  Some compilers in non-conforming mode will evaluate `sizeof (void)` to be 1, but it's just generally a bad idea.  Better to declare `a` as a pointer to a non-`void` type.

Comment: regarding: `printf("Dereferenced: %p\n", *box->value);`  the '%p' is expecting an address. but the '*box->value' is dereferencing that address to access the actual `int` value.  So there is a mismatch between the output/format specifier and the parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the `nop()` function has "side effects" just as a result of using the stack. The problem is in the `makeBox()` function which is setting a pointer to a stack variable. I added some comments in the snippet:

```
struct Box *makeBox(void) {
    // value is an integer pointer on the stack
    int *value = NULL;
    struct Box *box = malloc(sizeof *box);
    // box->value is set to the address of the stack location of value
    box->value = &value;
    return box;
}
```

When `nop()` allocates `a` on the stack it is essentially stomping on the stack where your other pointer was. This is an example of why you cannot return a pointer to a stack variable as that does not persist outside of the scope of the function in which it is allocated.

Comment: I was under the impression that using `malloc` would create the variable on the heap; and I'm only returning a pointer to the heap, so the stack should not be a problem to me. Could you address this (probable) misconception in your answer?

Comment: Sure. This line `int *value = NULL;` allocates an `int *` on the stack. Now, you later end up setting that pointer to point to a block of memory on the heap however the pointer itself is on the stack.

Comment: @Chiru the `struct `represented by `box` is on the heap, but `value` is not on the heap, so `&value` does not represent the address that exists in the heap. You assigned this temporal address to a member of the `box` structure.

Comment: What's the idiomatic C approach here? Could I get `value` onto the heap by initializing it as `int *value = malloc(0)`?

Comment: @Chiru: There's no "idiomatic approach" until you explain in detail what you are trying to do. Why is `box->value` even a pointer? Why is it a `**` pointer? The question makes no sense without knowing all that.

Comment: @AnT `makeBox` is supposed to initialize the members of a newly created `Box` struct, and then return a pointer to it. Basically, I don't want to trust the caller to initialize all the `Box` members; hence, I want to emulate something similar to a constructor.

Comment: @Chiru doesn't answer the more pressing question of why `value` in `Box` is a `int **`. While there are valid situations you would need two levels of indirection it could also be incorrect. As is - you could set `box->value = malloc(sizeof(int*))`. Keep in mind that `*(box->value)` would then be uninitialized as you would have allocated a pointer on the heap, not an integer itself. I would really try and figure out first if you intentionally want to define the structure that way.

Answer (score 2):

Your program has undefined behavior. `box->value` pointer inside `main` contains indeterminate value. Inside `makeBox` it used to point to a *local* variable `value`, but now `makeBox` is finished and that local variable is gone for good. Trying to dereference it as `*box->value` results in undefined behavior. That is what you observe.

Answer (score -1):

using your posted code (slightly reformated for readability:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Box
{
    int **value;
};


void nop(void)
{
    /* Why does this function have side effects? */
    void *a = malloc(sizeof *a);
    free(a);
}


struct Box *makeBox(void)
{
    int *value = NULL;
    struct Box *box = malloc(sizeof *box);
    box->value = &value;
    return box;
}


int main(void)
{
    struct Box *box = makeBox();
    printf("Dereferenced: %p\n", *box->value);
    nop();
    printf("Dereferenced: %p\n", *box->value);
}
```

always enable the warnings when compiling. then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use:

```
-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11
```

This will result in the compiler outputting several warning messages.

(just because the message says 'warning' rather than 'error' does not mean the warnings can be ignored.

The warnings:

1. :13:29: warning: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to a void type [-Wpointer-arith]
2. :30:12: warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type
   ‘void *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
3. :32:12: warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]

EDIT:
The `makebox()` function is returning the address of a local variable.  local variables go out-of-scope when the function exits.  so this is undefined behavior.

The above undefined behavior is a problem when the function: `nop()` is called. because it is using the same stack area as was used in the 'makebox()` function.

The local variable: `void *a` is using the same part of the stack as the `makebox()` function variable `value`.

so when the `main()` function dereferences the field in `struct Box, which points to the same area on the stack, and that area has been modified by the later call to`nop()`, then the value on the stack, at that area has been changed.

so the calls to `printf()` will, on the first call, pickup the original value and on the second call will pickup the address returned from the call to `malloc()`

I.E.  modify the code so it does not have any undefined behavior.  This can be done by either changing the `struct box` so it contains the actual data or move the local variable: `value` to some 'safe area', such as giving it file scope, perhaps by inserting the modifier `static` before the variable declaration